# How to get image in md-option after selection in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a md-select and i want to be able to have the value have a image as well. But i am not able to .

I searched and got to this issue https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2275.

But is there any work around .

My progress

```
  <div>
    <md-select placeholder="Icon" [(ngModel)]="actionHook.icon" name = "icon">
      <md-option *ngFor="let icon of icons" [value]="icon.display">
        <i class="material-icons customIcons">{{icon.display}}</i>
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
```

It only displays the icons in the Select but when i select the image only value comes no icon

Requirement

[image][image]

If i select i get the second where as i want the image along with the text and then the value passed as just the text . Hope i am clear

Comment: Their is a mismatch between the title and what you really ask for.
You want md-option to return an icon and a value.
But what does it mean, "You want the icon" 
Can you explain what data you expect ?

Comment: I want the icon as well as the icon to be displayed where as the value will be normal value that is passed to the select @TheSegfault

Comment: Any reason for DV

Comment: Are you google translating everything omg ? It is really hard to understand properly your needs...

Comment: @TheSegfault updated this is as verbose as it gets

Answer (score 0):

When you select an option in any dropdown or `md-select`. You get the value. not the icon.  You get the value you provide in `[value]` attribute.

```
<md-option *ngFor="let icon of icons" [value]="icon.display">
```

If you need to display the icon somewhere else in the template, then use,

`<i class="material-icons customIcons">{{EMITTED_VALUE}}</i>`

Comment: i need the icon as well as the value to be displayed , this is already known

Comment: The emitted value is listened by JS or TS code. I dont think you would use icon in JS or TS file. If you need to display the icon somewhere else then use,

`<i class="material-icons customIcons">{{EMITTED_VALUE}}</i>`